# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre los DTO y los ViewModels?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> No logro entender su diferencia y cual es el objetivo de usar el AutoMapper

Comment: Podrias mirar por favor [ask]? tu pregunta es como demasiado amplia. Porque no explicas que entendiste hasta ahora y partimos de ahi?

Answer (score 5):

Un ViewModel es una clase de modelo que puedes utilizar para tarabajar con vistas, ejemplo a la hora de renderizar un formulario complejo basado en clases, la diferencia que tiene es que esta clase no es utilizada por tu ORM para persistir datos mientras que los DTO son clases que Entity Framework mapea a tu BD

Un caso muy común en el que utilizo ViewModels es cuando quiero crear un formulario que contenga datos de 2 o más clases, en este caso creo un ViewModel con los parámetros que necesito y creo mi formulario basado en ese ViewModel con sus validaciones.

Sobre el uso de AutoMapper.
Como te explicaba el ViewModel sirve como una clase de vista que vamos a utilizar con el objetivo de mostrar datos complejos o crear formularios personalizados que utilicen más de una clase, pero al mandar los datos de este formulario basado en una clase en este caso tu ViewModel a un controlador, EF no sabe cómo guardar esa información puesto que no existe tal tabla en tu BD por eso Utilizamos AutoMapper para separar los datos del ViewModel y asignárselos a cada una de las clases involucradas antes de guardar en tu BD

ejemplo, tenemos la clase Trabajador y la clase Usuario cada una con sus atributos y queremos en un formulario crear un Usuario y al mismo tiempo un Trabajador, si utilizamos un Formualrio fuertemente tipado a una clase sólo podremos utilizar un modelo, ó Trabajador ó Usuario en la vista, en este caso puedes crear un ViewModel con nombre TrabajadorUserViewModel con los atributos de las 2 clases y ahora si puedes crear tu formulario basado en ese modelo con sus validaciones mediante DataAnnotations y todo, es como una clase más pero que EF no la va a utilizar para guardar en BD como con Trabajador y Usuario. hasta aqui todo bien el punto es que TrabajadorUserviewModel recoge todos los datos en el formulario y necesitas separar todo eso y asignarle los datos que le corresponden a cada clase en tu controlador, ahi es donde se utiliza AutoMapper, espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Por favor revisa tu ortografía, es información válida pero pierde seriedad cuando lees un "ke" y "my formulario".

Comment: gracias por tu comentario, son las malas costumbres

Comment: Malas costumbres que cualquiera puede tener. Fuera de eso, buena respuesta!